# Value after hoisting?

Tags: javascript, function, expression, hoisting

Question: What will be the value of bar after it is hoisted?

```
var bar = function() {
return 3;
};
```

I think: the function expression. I'm wrong?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you expect as an answer... every variable has the value `undefined` initially, until the line of the assignment is executed. And in this case, `bar` is assigned a function. What do you think *hoisting* is?

Answer (score 4):

Why not just try it?

```
var bar = function() {
    return 3;
 };

console.log(bar);
```

Output,

```
  function () {
    return 3;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, but: what's in this case the difference between hoisted or not? How can I simulate hoisting?

Comment: I think maybe you only provided part of the relevant code. Hoisting isn't really relevant here, I'm guessing your example called bar somewhere further up?

Comment: console.log(bar); // undefined

    var bar = function() {
    return 3;
    };

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Hoisting will make "bar" defined higher in the code than where the var bar assignment actually is; see http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html for a good tutorial on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the function. So yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use an undefined variable then that will of course throw a reference error. If you try to assign to an undefined variable then it will create a global variable (in a web page, roughly equivalent to writing `window.foo = bar;`). However the variable will still be undefined until it is created.

If however you declare a local variable using `const` or `var`, then it will be defined from the beginning of the function as having the value `undefined`, so accessing the variable "early" will not throw a reference error, and setting it will set the local value. You do not have to declare the variable at the start of the function; the declaration will be *hoisted* to the scope of the function.

By comparison, in ES6, if you declare a variable using `let`, then it will only be hoisted to the beginning of the block.

Also, if you declare a "variable" using `function`, then its value will be hoisted too, so you can call a function before its declaration. (The function has to be in the same script though.)